# How to use union all with manual value (not from another tabel)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, union, union-all

I want to use union all with manual value, not from another table. And the values are:

```
|cSatuan1|cSatuan2|nkonversi|
=============================
|   LTR  |   PCS  |    1    |
|   PCS  |   LTR  |    1    |
```

I've made the query with my own way, but it gets error. here is the query:

```
SELECT csatuan2, csatuan1, nkonversi
FROM ms_metriks union all select 'LTR','PCS','1','PCS','LTR','1'
```

Can you tell me what's wrong with my query, and what is the right query?

Comment: For future reference, it would be more helpful if you posted the actual error message you receive in your question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT csatuan2,csatuan1,nkonversi FROM ms_metriks 
UNION ALL SELECT 'LTR','PCS','1'
UNION ALL SELECT 'PCS','LTR','1'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way you can do it:

```
SELECT 'LTR' as csatuan1,'PCS' as csatuan2,'1' as nkonversi
UNION
SELECT 'PCS','LTR','1';
```

Comment: it's work, but the results of this query are not what I mean. btw, thank you for your answer, I still can use it for another query :)

Answer (score 0):

I dare to add my experince with Oracle. I had there very similar problem, how to select usernames from table and add to result value 'admin':

There was a problem that this query:

```
select
  username      
from users
union 
  select 'admin'
```

returned a error:

```
Error at Command Line : 5 Column : 17
Error report -
SQL Error: "FROM keyword not found where expected"
```

As solution I add added 'dummy' from part with the same table:

```
select
  username     
from users
union 
  select 'admin' 
  from users
```

And it works.

J.