# TSQL Union in sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a table called `Employee.emp.Language` that contains a list of languages to choose from on the UI. I am unable to add a record to this table and unable to edit the UI directly to solve my problem.

I need to add an option to my query that adds `NULL` into my result set. This essentially will allow a user to pick `null` from the drop-down list.

```
DECLARE @nulls AS TABLE (fieldLabel VARCHAR(10) NULL, fieldValue VARCHAR(10) 

NULL)
INSERT INTO @nulls( fieldLabel, fieldValue )
VALUES  ('NULL', NULL )

SELECT 
(
        SELECT  LanguageName AS FieldLabel,
                LanguageID AS FieldValue
        FROM    Employee.emp.Language
        WHERE  IsRetired = 0
        UNION
        SELECT fieldLabel ,
                fieldValue
            FROM @nulls
    FOR    XML PATH ('options'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT ('languages') 
)
```

While my list contains the `null` option to select in my dropdown, I am having trouble getting this piece of code to save into my stored procedure.

The error I am getting is: `The FOR XML clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, and subqueries when they contain a set operator. To work around, wrap the SELECT containing a set operator using derived table syntax and apply FOR XML on top of it.`

As soon as I remove the `union` and the `select` following it, all works fine.

How else could I accomplish adding a value to the result set without adding it to the table directly?

Comment: Why must be 'NULL'. NULL = Unknown. You can insert a record to the table Employee.emp.Language which LanguageName = 'Unknown'.

Comment: @Wendy - I am unable to modify the source table by adding this record. I am hacking up a solution for a small workaround where the other 99% of the time, NULL will not be an option that is selectable nor appear in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it as a subquery, and you don't need a table valued, you can use a select with null values.

> ```
> create table lang(fieldlabel varchar(10), fieldvalue varchar(20));
> insert into lang values 
> ('en', 'english'),
> ('fr', 'french');
>
> select fieldlabel, fieldvalue
> from (select fieldlabel, fieldvalue
>       from   lang
>       union all
>       select null as fieldlabel, null as fieldvalue) l
> FOR    XML PATH ('options'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT ('languages')
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name)                                                                                                                                                                              |
> | :-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | <languages><options><fieldlabel>en</fieldlabel><fieldvalue>english</fieldvalue></options><options><fieldlabel>fr</fieldlabel><fieldvalue>french</fieldvalue></options><options /></languages> |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=9af867b38f48175d89153365ea751a71)*

Comment: This worked great - The one thing I cant figure out though is how to add an order by clause into this scenario. Trying to order by lang table in asc order with the null at the end. Currently, null does come last but there is no order on the results. When I try to add one, I get the error: "The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified."

Comment: you can order it by adding `top 100 percent` http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=de44a83c0e6f8caa5ccaa9007bb961a4

Comment: Thanks, I gave that a shot but for some reason, the order still remains incorrect. I was trying to add a few more examples to your query to test it but I couldn't see how to edit it. Your fiddle is showing in the same order the results are in so I just wanted to add a few more to see if yours is sorting correctly.

Comment: Please, post the link to dbfiddle and I will try to solve it.

Comment: I just figured it out actually, I moved the order by to the outer select and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting the null values directly instead of using a separate table.  Try:

```
UNION ALL SELECT 'PCS','LTR','1'
```

From [How to use union all with manual value (not from another tabel)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733010/how-to-use-union-all-with-manual-value-not-from-another-tabel)

Note: Edited answer

Comment: He is inserting a string of "Null" and a null value into the value field `INSERT INTO @nulls (
 fieldLabel
 , fieldValue
 )
VALUES (
 'NULL'
 , NULL
 )`